# 500 Internal Server Error - Error logs do not show anything significant

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, fastcgi

First of all, thank you for your time in reading this :)

I am managing a server which runs apache2 and mod_fcgi which host a few sites via Virtual Hosts.  Some sites are straight PHP, the others are all WordPress.  The WordPress sites are all functioning great, however, any other site throws up a 500 Internal Server Error when you try to access them.

If you navigate to a non-php file on the web directory (like an image) it will display, but any .php file throws up this error.

The Apache2 error log shows nothing.

When I tail the error log of the site, I get this:

```
[Wed May 22 15:12:15 2013] [warn] [client x.x.x.x] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Wed May 22 15:12:15 2013] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Premature end of script headers: php-fcgi-wrapper
[Wed May 22 15:12:15 2013] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client x.x.x.x] Zlib: Compressed 612 to 377 : URL /fcgi-bin/php-fcgi-wrapper/index.php
```

The root of the website is located in /var/www/site1/

I have quadrouple-checked my permissions and ownerships.
I have increased more memory for PHP.
I tried looking at the php.log file, but nothing is being written.

Can anyone point anything else out that could be causing this?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked to see if CGI is conflicting here? I seem to remember that being a problem with a few sites of mine a while back. Unfortunately I dont have the time to look up the solution (can't remember it) but take that avenue if you don't get any responses.

Comment: Error 500 with mod_fcgi ( or mod_fastcgi ) is rather common with apache/fcgi/php combination, you will see it often. Configuration of this is very complicated, there's separate logging for each component. I guess in your case you configured fcgi wrongly to work with php, anyway error 500 usually signals loss of connection between fcgi app and webserver. It is not simple to configure it, and I would not expect some straight, simple solution for your case. There's really many things which may lead to result you described. Debug, debug, debug. Verbose, verbose, verbose. Debug, debug, debug.

Comment: In most cases it is caused by invalid configured number of apache childs/threads in relation with number allowed fcgi forks (mod_fcgi options ), in relation with amount of resources allowed for php, or even with number of files per process across the system. It maybe some easy-to-find obvious error in configuration, but it may also be really hard to track, number of options, their meaning and their relations between components make huge selection of causes..

Comment: If possible, you might want to try lighthttpd or sth for fcgi instead of apache, really. Apache was invented looooong time before fcgi, and despite all its advantages, it is a long and painful track to make it work reasonably stable with it, in context of simple "is my webpage loading and why error 500 again?" :)

Comment: http://dtpw.pl/mywork/user1000.jpg :)

Comment: Have you tried runninga  simple script? 
like  <?= 'a'; ?> just to check if the problem if within yoru application or evirioment

Comment: @dudewad, How can I check to see if CGI is conflicting? Any quick hints?

Comment: @DaniloKobold- I am assuming since the 500 error is within a whole family of websites that the error doesn't resolve in the application itself, am I right in assuming this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the time at the moment to back up my cgi-conflict suggestion, but it occurred to me that you may be using php short tags, when the server doesn't allow it. Wordpress I believe uses full open tags which would explain why it works.
Instead of using:

```
<? //some php code 
?>
```

Try:

```
<?php //some php code
?>
```

Are you using short tags? This could be your issue.

Comment: :( No sir, all tags used are <?php ?>